# How do I chain promises before returning?

Tags: ionic-framework, promise, observable, chaining

Ok, I'm trying to encode image files to base64 and then make a POST to the API and return the response.

The trouble I'm having is, the base64 encodes run async, so it's not making the api post before the encoding has completed.

Any help appreciated.

```
makePost()
  {
    return Observable.create((observer) => {

      this.myPost.base64images = new Array(10);

      for (var i = 0; i < this.myPost.images.length; i++)
      {
        if (this.myPost.images[i])
        {
          this.base64.encodeFile(this.myPost.images[i].path).then((base64File: string) => {

            this.myPost.base64images[i] = base64File;

          }, (err) => {

            this.myPost.base64images[i] = null;
          });
        }
      }

      observer.next(1);
      observer.complete();

    }).pipe(mergeMap((result) => {

      var payload = {
        PostTitle: "Hello",
        Images: this.myPost.base64images
      }

      return this.apiService.makePost(payload).pipe(map(
        response => {

          return response;
        },
        err => {

          return err;
        }
      ));

    }));
  }
```

Comment: You'll want to have a look at `Promise.all`

Comment: edited my post with a Promise.all attempt, I'm still stuck though. :/

Comment: actually working, cheers.

Comment: So the `this.saveImageAsBase64(…)` method now does the `base64.encodeFile`? Btw, you really should still use a loop :-)